# asp.net 5 GC takes 10 seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, garbage-collection

I have a standard asp.net 5 application with EF and a PostgreSQL database.
I found out that the GC runs take a few seconds. Now I am wondering if this is normal behavior? All incoming requests are blocked for like 10 seconds.

This is a screenshot of dotMemory:
[image: This is a screenshot of dotMemory]

### Update (GCStats)

After waiting for two GC runs time went down to `~3sec`. I now also used Release configuration.
Here is the GCStats view. I captured 5 GC runs, all above the 200msec mark. I noticed that there is a high Gen0 fragmentation.

[image: GCStats of 5 GC runs]

Comment: Not an expert. Yet, I wonder why your application caps at 755MB. It does not seem to be much.

Comment: Hmm... I would say, definitely not normal, especially in this total amount of memory. It would be nice if you could get the data by [dotnet-trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-trace) with `gc-collect` profile and update the question with the `GC Stats` view of the resulting file from the [PerfView](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview) tool.

Comment: Ok, so you are allocating around 27MB/s which occasionally triggers Gen0 GC when it gets above 400MB. Unfortunatelly, this does not explain ~3 seconds pauses which are much too long for such a small gen 0. Unfortunatelly here's where nice tooling ends - if you want to, you can use PerfView as [described by Maoni Stephens](https://github.com/Maoni0/mem-doc/blob/master/doc/.NETMemoryPerformanceAnalysis.md#debugging-a-random-long-gc) to profile those long GCs - the reason may be similar to the one described there: there was a high priority process starving GC threads.